# Safe default value for missing street address number when reverse geocoding?

Tags: reverse-geocoding, here-maps

## Context

We are building an app that reverse geocodes a user location to retrieve a street address. The street address is then used to request transportation pick-up at the person's location.

## Problem

The transportation company needs a street address including **street address number** (the '123' in '123 Main St.') in order to dispatch a ride. However, the street number is not available in 100% of reverse geocoding results.

## Question

What are some options that might be safe to consider for **default street number value** when no data is available?

Comment: How is the driver supposed to locate that imaginary house number? You either need to interpolate from nearby house number (though you can still be wrong if houses are not evenly spaced, if odd/even numbers are on the same side of the street etc) or to just provide an address without a house number - which is valid in many cases

Comment: @JGH great suggestions. I will look into both interpolation and simply returning the address without a house number. Thanks :-)